# Understanding how JavaScript Prototypes work

Tags: javascript, prototype

Am messing around with prototypes to get a better understanding of how they work. I can't work out why I can't call hideHeader, whereas I can access a variable (this.header.el)

```
function App() {
    this.init();
    this.el = document.getElementById('box');
}

App.prototype.init = function () {
    document.write('hello world');

    this.header = new Header();

    this.header.hideHeader();
    this.header.el.style.display = 'none';
};

new App();

function Header() {
    this.el = document.getElementById('header');
}

Header.prototype.hideHeader = function() {
    this.el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Observe what happens when you move the call to `App()` at the bottom, and also note that `document.write` overwrites the document

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should reorder your code so that you *define* `hideHeader` before you try to invoke it.

Like this:

```
function App() {
    this.init();
    this.el = document.getElementById('box');
}

function Header() {
    this.el = document.getElementById('header');
}

Header.prototype.hideHeader = function() {
    this.el.style.display = 'none';
}

App.prototype.init = function () {
    document.write('hello world');

    this.header = new Header();

    this.header.hideHeader();
    this.header.el.style.display = 'none';
};

new App();
```

JavaScript is an interpreted language, it's not compiled.  It is evaluated sequentially as it is loaded into memory.

Comment: This is due to function hoisting - `Header` is hoisted, but not `hideHeader`.

Comment: i'm happy to help.  I think you should define init as part of the App function and not in the prototype.  I think it will make your code a little cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change the order of how you are doing things. For example:

```js
function App() {
    this.init();
    this.el = document.getElementById('box');
}


function Header() {
    this.el = document.getElementById('header');
}

Header.prototype.hideHeader = function() {
    this.el.style.display = 'none';
}

App.prototype.init = function () {
    document.write('hello world');

    this.header = new Header();

    this.header.hideHeader();
    this.header.el.style.display = 'none';
};

new App();
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="box"></div>
```